# What software testing tools can be used to test the media content like Video content loading in the web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-application

What software testing tools can be used to test the media content like Video content loading in the web page.

Mainly for an e-learning content like of Udemy's.

Video-playback and loading needs to be tested in web browser like desktop chrome and android chrome browser.
Using selenium we can check that video controls are working but how to check for different internet speeds,video seek to particular time, buffering etc..

Comment: I like the question, but maybe you should split it up: one question for videos and one for PDFs. For the latter there are already a few similar questions/answers: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdf

Comment: You can use imagemagick to verify video content is different to prove content is changing onscreen.